# Index of Indirect refference of unopened excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a report that generates an excel file with data in cells A1:T50. I need to make a trend excel that can pull data from those files dynamically depending on a difference in date. I'm down to the ability to properly reference the file and cell, and I can use that static output as a working index location but when I try to combine the two, with or without "INDIRECT()" it doesn't work.

I've gone over this for the indexing [Link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4226-excel-reference-unopened-file.html) and this from Microsoft [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)

I have the ability to create the text for the correct file location/file/cell range
I have the ability to output the needed cell from the closed Excel

Adding the dynamic reference to the indexing doesn't work

Closed file:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

Trend file:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 02 MAR 23 | Address Function works... |
| 02 MAR 23 | Index Function works... |
| 02 MAR 23 | Combined Function doesn't work... |

Grabs the correct address and syntax:

```
=CONCAT("'\\FileServer\Folder1\Folder 2\[Output Spreadsheet ",TEXT(INDIRECT(CONCAT("A"&ROW())),"dd mmm yy")," _ Test Template.xlsx]Roll-Up'!A:T")
```

Outputs the correct cell information:

```
=INDEX('\\FileServer\Folder1\Folder 2\[Output Spreadsheet 02 Mar 23 _ Test Template.xlsx]Roll-Up'!A:T,2,1)
```

Doesn't work:

```
=INDEX(CONCAT("'\\FileServer\Folder1\Folder 2\[Output Spreadsheet ",TEXT(INDIRECT(CONCAT("A"&ROW())),"dd mmm yy")," _ Test Template.xlsx]Roll-Up'!A:T"),2,1)
Output: #REF!
```

Comment: You can't use `INDIRECT` with an unopened file unfortunately.

Comment: Is there another formula that will create the location to use for the INDEX?

Comment: No, there is not another formula that will take a concatenated string and make it a viable range reference.  You could use vba to create the formula without the use of indirect, but it would most likely still require the opening and closing of the file.

Comment: But why would it work to create the proper cell output from the CONCAT, and the INDEX, but not work to combine them? The INDIRECT is only getting the date from the first column to use as the date in the name for INDEX.

Comment: INDIRECT is volatile and index is not.  Volatile functions recalc every time something in Excel changes.  INDEX itself will only recalc if the source data changes.  So with the workbook closed the source data will not change and therefore it will not recalculate.  But putting INDIRECT in it will force the recalc of the formula and since it is not open it will fail.